# Gaussian Elimination on Block Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I have a large matrix, with possibly over 100,000,000 elements in it and I want to solve it quickly. I want to take advantage of the fact that the matrix is partitioned into a small number of unique blocks, arranged in a symmetrical manner similar to a tridiagonal matrix.

$$
    \begin{matrix}
        a & b & c & d & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        e & f & b & c & d & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        g & b & f & b & c & d & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        h & c & b & f & b & c & d & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & d & c & b & f & b & c & d & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & d & c & b & f & b & c & h \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & d & c & b & f & b & g \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & d & c & b & f & e \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & d & c & b & a 
    \end{matrix}
$$ where a, b, c, d, e, and f are all $n \times n$ matrices whose determinants are known. Is there some way I could apply Gaussian Elimination at the block level so as to preserve the limited number of unique blocks I have, while finding the solution?

Update: The sub-matrices are commutable.